# Detecting Collisions Between Line and Image in Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm recreating the [Fruit Ninja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Ninja) game in python pygame. So far, I've added the slicing feature, which is a line that is drawn from the position of the mouse when it is first pressed down to the position of the mouse while it's down and in motion. Now I'm working on detecting collisions between the fruit and the line that slices the fruit. I'm trying to use the y=mx+b equation for this. Using the starting and ending points of the line, I calculate the slope (m) and using the slope, I calculate the b. Finally, I check if the line passes through the coordinates of the fruit. After trying to implement that, I've come across an issue. When trying to slice a fruit, the collision isn't detected. I think I know what's causing this issue: what about the width and the height of the fruit? After all, I am only checking if the line goes through the x and y position of the fruit, although the fruit isn't just one point, but an image full of points. Now my question is: how can I detect if the line goes through the **image** of the fruit and not just its position? I'm not sure how to do that using y=mx+b.
Code:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
pygame.init()

WINDOW_SIZE = (550, 550)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Ninja")
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30, "bold")

# List of fruit images
fruitsImages = [os.listdir("Fruits/" + path) for path in os.listdir("Fruits")]

# Images
heartImg = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
game_bg = pygame.image.load("BGs/woodenBG.png")
game_bg = pygame.transform.scale(game_bg, WINDOW_SIZE)
menuBG = pygame.image.load("BGs/menuBG.png")
menuBG = pygame.transform.scale(menuBG, WINDOW_SIZE)
gameLogo = pygame.image.load("fruitNinjaLogo.png")
gameLogo = pygame.transform.scale(gameLogo, (318, 197))
bombImg = pygame.image.load("bomb.png")


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3
        self.font = score_font
        self.heart = heartImg

    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.font.render(f"SCORE:{self.score}", True, (255, 255, 255)), (10, 10))

        x = 480
        for i in range(self.lives):
            window.blit(self.heart, (x, 10))
            x -= 60

    def init(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3


player = Player()


class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, fruit, x, y, upSpeed, downSpeed, fruitsList:list):
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.upSpeed = upSpeed
        self.downSpeed = downSpeed
        self.fruitsList = fruitsList

    def spawn(self):
        window.blit(self.fruit, (self.x, self.y))

    def throwUp(self):
        self.y -= self.upSpeed

    def drop(self):
        if self.y <= WINDOW_SIZE[1]:
            self.y += self.downSpeed
        else:
            self.fruitsList.remove(self)

    def checkIfCut(self, starting_point, ending_point):
        try:
            m = (starting_point[1] - ending_point[1]) / (starting_point[0] - ending_point[0])

            if starting_point[0] < 0:
                b = starting_point[1] + starting_point[0] * m
            else:
                b = starting_point[1] - starting_point[0] * m

            if self.y == m * self.x + b:
                print("Fruit Sliced")
            else:
                print("Fruit Not Sliced")

        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass


def swipe(starting_point, ending_point):
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), starting_point, ending_point, 5)


def blit_bg():
    window.blit(game_bg, (0, 0))


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    mouseDown = False
    fruit = Fruit(pygame.image.load("Fruits/RedApple/redApple.png"), 200, 200, 20, 50, [])
    while True:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        blit_bg()
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseDown = True
                starting_point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if mouseDown and event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                ending_point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                swipe(starting_point, ending_point)
                fruit.checkIfCut(starting_point, ending_point)

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouseDown = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                    player.init()
                    menu()

        fruit.spawn()

        player.update()
        pygame.display.update()


def menu():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("cooperblack", 90)
    while True:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(menuBG, (0, 0))
        window.blit(gameLogo, (120, 80))

        playButton = pygame.draw.rect(window, "#ff5c70", (130, 335, 300, 120))
        window.blit(font.render("PLAY", True, (0, 0, 0)), (150, 340))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if playButton.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    main()

        pygame.display.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

I hope what I said is clear. If something is unclear, please let me know.

With the help of @user16038533, the problem was solved! He also linked [this](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-rect.php) page, which helped me understand his solution.
Code:

```
import pygame
import random
import os
pygame.init()

WINDOW_SIZE = (550, 550)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)

pygame.display.set_caption("Fruit Ninja")
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30, "bold")

# List of fruit images
fruitsImages = [os.listdir("Fruits/" + path) for path in os.listdir("Fruits")]

# Images
heartImg = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
game_bg = pygame.image.load("BGs/woodenBG.png")
game_bg = pygame.transform.scale(game_bg, WINDOW_SIZE)
menuBG = pygame.image.load("BGs/menuBG.png")
menuBG = pygame.transform.scale(menuBG, WINDOW_SIZE)
gameLogo = pygame.image.load("fruitNinjaLogo.png")
gameLogo = pygame.transform.scale(gameLogo, (318, 197))
bombImg = pygame.image.load("bomb.png")


class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3
        self.font = score_font
        self.heart = heartImg

    def update(self):
        window.blit(self.font.render(f"SCORE:{self.score}", True, (255, 255, 255)), (10, 10))

        x = 480
        for i in range(self.lives):
            window.blit(self.heart, (x, 10))
            x -= 60

    def init(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3


player = Player()


class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, fruit, x, y, upSpeed, downSpeed, fruitsList:list):
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.upSpeed = upSpeed
        self.downSpeed = downSpeed
        self.fruitsList = fruitsList
        self.width, self.height = fruit.get_size()

    def spawn(self):
        window.blit(self.fruit, (self.x, self.y))

    def throwUp(self):
        self.y -= self.upSpeed

    def drop(self):
        if self.y <= WINDOW_SIZE[1]:
            self.y += self.downSpeed
        else:
            self.fruitsList.remove(self)

    def checkIfCut(self, starting_point, ending_point):
        x1, y1 = starting_point
        x2, y2 = ending_point

        if self.lineRectIntersecton(x1, y1, x2, y2):
            print("Fruit Sliced")
        else:
            print("Fruit Not Sliced")

    def lineRectIntersecton(self, startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY):
        left = self.lineLineIntersection(startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY, self.x, self.y, self.x,
                                    self.y + self.height)
        right = self.lineLineIntersection(startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY, self.x + self.width,
                                          self.y, self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)
        top = self.lineLineIntersection(startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY, self.x, self.y,
                                   self.x + self.width, self.y)
        bottom = self.lineLineIntersection(startingX, startingY, endingX, endingY, self.x,
                                           self.y + self.height, self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)

        return left or right or top or bottom

    @staticmethod
    def lineLineIntersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4):
        uAd = ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))
        uBd = ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1) - (x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1))
        if uAd != 0 and uBd != 0:
            uA = ((x4 - x3) * (y1 - y3) - (y4 - y3) * (x1 - x3)) / uAd
            uB = ((x2 - x1) * (y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1) * (x1 - x3)) / uBd

            return 0 <= uA <= 1 and 0 <= uB <= 1
        return False


def swipe(starting_point, ending_point):
    pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 255, 255), starting_point, ending_point, 5)


def blit_bg():
    window.blit(game_bg, (0, 0))


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    mouseDown = False
    fruit = Fruit(pygame.image.load("Fruits/RedApple/redApple.png"), 200, 200, 20, 50, [])
    while True:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        blit_bg()
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouseDown = True
                starting_point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if mouseDown and event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                ending_point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                swipe(starting_point, ending_point)
                fruit.checkIfCut(starting_point, ending_point)

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouseDown = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                    player.init()
                    menu()

        fruit.spawn()

        player.update()
        pygame.display.update()


def menu():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("cooperblack", 90)
    while True:
        window.fill((0, 0, 0))
        window.blit(menuBG, (0, 0))
        window.blit(gameLogo, (120, 80))

        playButton = pygame.draw.rect(window, "#ff5c70", (130, 335, 300, 120))
        window.blit(font.render("PLAY", True, (0, 0, 0)), (150, 340))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if playButton.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    main()

        pygame.display.update()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    menu()
```

I hope this question can benefit other people who are struggling with the same problem.

Comment: You should save the image's width and height and take those into account when checking for a collision.

Comment: Why are you reloading your background image every time?

Comment: @The_spider, should I load the background image outside of the blit_bg() function?

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski, I’m not sure how to implement it. Can you please explain in an answer?

Comment: I think 'How do I implement this' is too broad for an SO question, but this may help https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111100/intersection-of-a-line-and-a-rectangle

Comment: @JeffUK, I want to implement the collision using the y=mx+b equation, which is what I asked for in my question. I know how to check if a line goes through a certain point, but I'm not sure how I'd check if a line goes through an image, and not just a certain point in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you don't know how to do things, you google it. You can check if your line is colliding against any of the lines that make up the rectangle. [Here](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-rect.php) is where I got the code from.

```
def lineLineIntersection(x1,  y1,  x2,  y2,  x3,  y3,  x4,  y4):
    uAd = ((y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1))
    uBd = ((y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1))
    if uAd != 0 and uBd != 0:
        uA = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3)) / uAd
        uB = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3)) / uBd

        return uA >= 0 and uA <= 1 and uB >= 0 and uB <= 1

    return False

def lineRectIntersecton(x1, y1, x2, y2, rx, ry,  rw, rh):
    return lineLineIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2, rx,ry,rx, ry+rh) \
    or lineLineIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2, rx+rw,ry, rx+rw,ry+rh) \
    or lineLineIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2, rx,ry, rx+rw,ry) \
    or lineLineIntersection(x1,y1,x2,y2, rx,ry+rh, rx+rw,ry+rh)
```

and with that you can change your `checkIfCut` function to:

```
def checkIfCut(self, starting_point, ending_point):
    x1, y1 = starting_point
    x2, y2 = ending_point
    rw, rh = self.fruit.get_size()
    
    return lineRectIntersecton(x1, y1, x2, y2, self.x, self.y, rw, rh)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works in the code, but the `lineLineIntersection()` and `lineRectIntersection()` functions aren't very readable to me.

Comment: which part ? You can check the link for the original code if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the original link and changed the format of some of the code and also changed some of the variable names. Now it's easier for me to read.